# Point Domain Name To Own IP

Tags: nameserver, domain-name

I have just bought a new domain name through Crazy Domains, but not DNS routing.

At the moment the name servers are pointing to Crazy Domain, but I would like web traffic to go to my own IP address.

Do I need to purchase the DNS hosting options? Or can I change the name server to my IP?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to point DNS for the domain to a DNS server. You can use Crazy Domains DNS servers, find a 3rd party or host your own. I'd suggest you use Crazy Domains DNS.

Answer (score 1):

You will need DNS servers - at two different IP addresses. Either you can host your own (again though, you will need at least 2 IP addresses for your nameservers) or you can use your registrar's or you can use one of the free DNS services.

Take a look at [How to assign a domain name to my server box's IP Address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/298530/how-to-assign-a-domain-name-to-my-server-boxs-ip-address) for a list of some free DNS providers and additional information.

I would recommend the free DNS providers if your registrar does not provide DNS for free.